# How do I restrict the number of rows in a table for a specific column value?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to do this in postgreSQL:
You can't store more than 5 records (rows).

```
CREATE FUNCTION contar_dest()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM "LUGARES" WHERE demanda is not null) > 5
THEN 
DELETE FROM "LUGARES"
WHERE ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM "LUGARES");
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER contar
AFTER INSERT
ON "LUGARES"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE contar_dest();
```

When I try to insert a row show me this:

ERROR: execution reached the end of trigger procedure without finding RETURN
CONTEXT : PL / pgSQL function contar_dest ()

Now I do what I want but the error is this now:

```
CREATE FUNCTION contar_dest()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$body$
BEGIN
IF ((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM "LUGARES" WHERE demanda is not null) > 5) THEN 
DELETE FROM "LUGARES"
WHERE ID = (SELECT NEW.ID FROM "LUGARES");
ELSIF ((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM "LUGARES" WHERE demanda is not null) < 5) THEN
RETURN NULL;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER contar
AFTER INSERT
ON "LUGARES"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE contar_dest();

INSERT INTO "LUGARES"(
        nombre, demanda)
VALUES ('Valencia',2000);

ERROR: a subquery used as an expression returned more than one record
CONTEXT : SQL statement : " DELETE FROM "LUGARES"
    WHERE ID = ( SELECT FROM NEW.ID "LUGARES") »
PL / pgSQL contar_dest ( ) function in line 4 SQL statement
********** Error **********
```

Comment: There is not ELSE in your query so you don't return anything when the IF is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by you using syntax that requires maximum of 1 row, but when executed returns many.

Change:

```
DELETE FROM "LUGARES"
WHERE ID = (SELECT NEW.ID FROM "LUGARES");
```

To:

```
DELETE FROM "LUGARES"
WHERE ID IN (SELECT NEW.ID FROM "LUGARES");
```

`=` only works with 1 value, but `IN` allows many values.